# WinForms TreeView.Sorted Property and VS 2008 Object Browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, treeview, intellisense

I can't see the above property neither in the object browser nor in intellisense for TreeView, why is this? I can set in my code though, it and the project builds successfully. When I gight click it and select 'go to definition' it is shown like a public bool property. Is this normal, or have I messed something up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sorted property is marked with `BrowsableAttribute(false)`, which stops it appearing in the property grid, and with `EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)`, which stops it appearing in Intellisense.  So yes, this is normal: for whatever reason, the person who designed that API wanted to discourage you from seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see it because it is hidden:

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

Normally, the assumption is that it makes sense in a base-class, but isn't supported for the current type `TreeView` - but `TreeView` inherits from `Control`, so I'm not sure what is going on here! In particular, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.sorted.aspx) doesn't make any comments that suggest any reason why it is hidden, unless perhaps it conflicted with the designer (node editor).

Comment: My guess for "why Browsable(false)" is that it makes sense only when TreeViewNodeSorter is set, which can't be done in the property grid.  Doesn't explain why it's hidden from Intellisense though, unless they're just trying to get people to use the Sort() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this out and using this property seems to work ok for me however I notice that if you set the treeview to use a TreeViewNodeSorter it sorts automatically without needing to touch this.